# Re : RS422 module from Aliexpress

Tags: rs485, rs422

Was planning to work on some long distance communications with RS485 / RS422 and I saw one of these boards on Aliexpress,Amazon etc..
Does anyone know what all those passive components could be?
Would love if anyone has seen a schematic of any of these boards any reference schematic for the same.

[image: RS422 Module]
Cheers and TIA

Comment: If anything isn't explained to your satisfaction on the datasheet, don't buy it.

Comment: Its not all that expensive,I would buy it just to reverse engineer and study it, but I guess "good luck" with any courier and deliveries these days. The photo shows up as a MAX490 which is logical. Might be 2 termination resistors, and a decoupling capacitor. Was just curious about those "diode" like things (transzorbs perhaps) ?

Comment: Why would you buy something that has unknown origins (in terms of quality and manufacturer) and is sold through a (currently) disreputable supplier of electronic circuit products? Why would you buy something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Web searching on the module part number finds assorted seller pages claiming that TVS diodes are provided.

The mystery components are in a sensible position for such a role.

An SMD package such as DO214 is suitable for such a component and has the general appearance of those on the board, though the exact physical sizing isn't immediately easy to guess.

Undocumented modules are always a gamble.  On the plus side, simple ones where you can visually follow the traces and readily re-work the external components can give you some flexibility to quickly get something going.  On the minus, you have to take the time to understand, and you are sourcing the central chip from the grey market...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the resistors are biasing the RS485 lines so they have known values when undriven.

At least one of the resistors is providing termination.

Some of the resistors are pulling the IC's inputs to good values because they shouldn't be left floating.

The caps are bypass and bulk.

(I had one of these and studied it for a few moments before using it.)